# Help me identify this book about friendly aliens living covertly on Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't remember the name or much of the plot of a book I read as a child in the 1970's. It had to do with friendly aliens that looked like humans. They lived covertly on Earth. The book cover had a window that opened in the air that they could travel through. 
I don't remember much more except that it really stirred my early imagination. I would love to figure out what it was.

Comment: The plot sounds like Zenna Henderson's [*People*](http://www.nesfa.org/press/Books/Henderson.htm) series, but I'm not seeing a cover that matches.

Comment: There are many, many stories about friendly aliens that look like humans. _Rain Rain Go Away_ by Asimov was the first that sprung to mind.